# GRUB2 won't send any video signal to my screen on boot (Ubuntu MATE 20.04)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, mate

> DISCLAMERS

I'm new.

I'm french so I'm not that good in English if you see what I mean...
Thanks for your understanding.

Faucon

> **Essential information**

*I have the boot menu on with a 30 seconds delay*

*I have Windows 10 on dualboot with linux.*

It started when my screen on my laptop broke approximatly 6 months ago, (I had Kubuntu installed, but now at the time I'm writing this I have Ubuntu MATE 20.04) so I got the idea to plug in a monitor (a VGA one because I only have this) and then I realized that *there what not any video signal when it was booting, not even the logo of my laptop brand (FUJITSU)*.

> **Issue**

I have a problem with GRUB2 or/and my BIOS about why my BIOS/GRUB2 won't send any video signal (not even a green screen or something like that) when I'm booting, I searched everywhere but it looks like I'm the only one who have this issue.

> **What I have tried**

So I searched on the internet and then I found that on my favorite  [ubuntu documentation](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org) website that we could add a beep when the GRUB2 menu starts so I added the beep to be more clear when GRUB2 started.

Then I remembered the order that GRUB2 displayed my 2 OS, it was something like that:

```
Ubuntu XX.XX
More options for Ubuntu XX.XX
Windows Boot Manager
UEFI Settings
```

(UEFI Settings = BIOS)

So when it beeped, I wanted to boot on Windows so I pressed two times bottom arrow and pressed enter, there was still nothing but I waited, and then I got signal that showed me the blue screen with "Wait" (Not BSOD) so I was like yay! So cool... And then I booted on linux, did the same thing that Windows did (but with linux graphics, of course). But it's not enough for me, I can't change BIOS options without changing the in-board screen by a old one (that don't fit in the case) temporarly and that's SO ANNOYING (sorry for caps)

> What I need

I need that GRUB2 and the BIOS send a video signal to my screen when it boot.
All help is appreciated.

> Source

[doc.ubuntu-fr.org](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org) (Awesome french site, you can always use an extension to translate the website or use Google Chrome, where I learned that we can add a beep when GRUB2 starts.)

Comment: Not sure that can be done I have the exact same with my Toshiba laptop it seems to be how it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you know if there's a software that can modify the BIOS or something like that?